# Tomcat RemoteHost Valve setup gives back HTTP 403

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to modify a Tomcat (7.0.52) valve definition to allow contact from a different server.

The valve definition looks like that shown below.  Previously, it was a RemoteAddrValve and defined with 127.0.0.1 (to only allow access from local host).  This worked perfectly.  For the new definition the AddrValve was changed to a HostValve and the full-qualified-domain-name of the remote server was entered.  Now when hitting that Tomcat instance from that remote server, I always get a Http 403: 'Access to the specified resource has been forbidden'.

```
<Context debug="0" swallowOutput="true">

    <!-- This causes session data to NOT be persisted to disk across tomcat restarts -->
    <Manager pathname=""/>

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
             directory="logs"  prefix="blackduck_solr_access_log." suffix=".txt"
             pattern='%{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}t [%I] %h "%r" %s %b'/>

    <!-- JVCS-646 solr access to  localhost only -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteHostValve"
            allow="FQDN_HERE" />
</Context>
```

I did not set this server up and am clearly not expert in Tomcat Security.  The contents shown above were put into a file in this directory: ./tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost

I know the file is being processed because I get errors if the syntax is not correct.  Also if I remove it then access is wide open.  Can anyone help with what might be wrong?

Comment: Two points: 1) Is the hostname resolvable from the host tomcat is deployed to? 2) Are you aware that `allow=""` contains a regexp, not a a string?

Comment: #1. Fair point, yes, both ping and nslookup resolve the host just fine.  #2. I know it is a regexp, but have been proceeding assuming the '.''s from the FQDN in the regex will match the 'period's in the actual FQDN.

Comment: Is the 403ed access logged by the AccessLogValve? If so, matches the logged hostname the hostname from the RemoteHostValve?

Comment: I have the same problem in tomcat8 @see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577035/tomcat-8-remotehostvalve-not-working

did you try to add:

`enableLookups="true"`  ?