# Tomcat 8 RemoteHostValve not working

Tags: tomcat8, remote-host

The access to my server should be limited to some Remote hosts, and I want to allow Uptimerobot to monitor my server.

Currently uptimerobot gets always a 403 Forbidden.

I added Server.xml looks like this:

```
<Server .........>
  <Service name="Catalina">
      <Engine>
        <Value className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteHostValve" allow=".*\.uptimerobot\.com" />
      </Engine>
  </Service>
```

To match all hosts in this list [UptimeRobot Whitelist](https://uptimerobot.com/inc/files/ips/hostnames.txt)

But after restarting server nothing changed, still 403.

I also tried to use a domain-name without wildcards like this:

```
allow="engine19\.uptimerobot\.com"
allow="engine19.uptimerobot.com"
```

But still 403,

I tried to enable hostnamelookups with adding

```
enableLookups="true"
```

to the `<Connector`
tag, but again no effect.

But in my logs I see that the access is resolved to "engine19.uptimerobot.com" wich matches my RemoteHost-Pattern.

Any Ideas, why it is still forbidden ?

## EDIT:

Access via IP with

```
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="63\.143\.42\.244"/>
```

is working. But I dont want to add the whole list of ips there.
Is it possible that `RemoteAddrValve` and `RemoteHostValve` are disturbing eachother ?

Comment: Can you please tell me how you resolve this issue?
Becuase i face same issue.

Comment: Unfurtunally I did not find any solution for this problem yet :(

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and this worked for me

set useIPVHosts to true in connector (Inside server.xml).

I am using HTTP connector and it looks as follow

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443"
    enableLookups="true"
    useIPVHosts="true" />
```

[Details of attributes can be found here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Check tomcat/logs/local_access_log... to see what host name used for 403.

I found that our company DNS reports some names in all uppercase and others in all lowercase. Use (?i) to have regex be case insensitive:

```
allow="(?i)engine19\.uptimerobot\.com"
```

If you have both RemoteHostValve and RemoteAddValve, both must allow an incoming host. If either does not allow then 403 will be returned.

Comment: But if I try to allow any host accordiing the domainpattern, I dont like to add each ip address.